# Select records when 2 column's data will match

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables as shown below:

```
 -----------------------
 |EmpNo|Complaint      |
 -----------------------
 |9091 |Change required|
 |9092 |No change      |
 |9093 |Changes done   |
 -----------------------
```

Above table contains employee number and his complaints.

I have one another table which contains employee all kind of details as shown below.

```
-------------------------------
|EmpNo|EmailID      |EmpBossNO|
-------------------------------
|9091 |abc@gmail.com|9092     |
|9092 |xyz@gmail.com|9093     |
|9093 |mno@gmail.com|9099     |
-------------------------------
```

Here, if `Empno:9091` will raise any complain then a mail will send to his `boss` that the complain is raise by your employee and you have to accept it so I want to get `EmailID` of employee's boss and for that I want one SQL query. I tried the query shown here, but it doesn't work.

```
select EmpEmailID
from tblComplaint
inner join tblEmpMaster on tblEmpMaster.EmpNo = tblComplaint.EmpPSNo
where tblComplaint.EmpPSNo = tblEmpMaster.EmpBossNo
```

I want output like.. if complaint is raised by `EmpNo:9091` then it will return EmailID of his boss which is `xyz@gmail.com`.

Comment: If you need the email of boss then you have to write another join table of boss and then in the select part set your boss email field to show the result but your example is not clear very well  if you can edit your question with better description of what you need you can get better answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right track with a join between the `tblComplaint` and `tblEmpMaster` tables.  But, you need an *additional* join to `tblEmpMaster` to bring in the boss' email for each employee complaint.

```
SELECT
    c.EmpNo,
    c.Complaint,
    COALESCE(e2.EmailID, 'NA') AS boss_email
FROM tblComplaint c
INNER JOIN tblEmpMaster e1
    ON c.EmpNo = e1.empNo
LEFT JOIN tblEmpMaster e2
    ON e1.EmpBossNO = e2.EmpNo;
```

[image]

### Demo

I used a left self join above, in case a given employee does not have a boss (e.g. for the highest ranking boss).  In this case, I display `NA` for the boss email.

Comment: It works perfectly so i marked it as answer..btw thanks @Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

You should self join `tblEmpMaster`

```
select boss.EmpEmailID
from tblComplaint
inner join tblEmpMaster emp on emp.EmpNo = tblComplaint.EmpPSNo
inner join tblEmpMaster boss on boss.EmpNo = emp.EmpBossNO
where tblComplaint.EmpPSNo = 9091
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gY33G3BBN2EW5ffZxjczPg/0)

Answer (score 0):

you can even use sub queries to get the Email_Id of the boss as shown below

```
SELECT Email_Id 
FROM EMP_Details 
WHERE Emp_No IN (
         SELECT Boss_Id 
         FROM Emp_Details) AND 
      Emp_No IN (
         SELECT Emp_No 
         FROM Emp_Complaints)
```